# How to convert J/mol-K to BTU/mol-R manually?

Tags: thermodynamics, units, si-units

How to convert $\frac{J}{mol-K}$ to $\frac{BTU}{mol-R}$ manually?

Sorry for such a simple question, I am new to Physics and I'm getting confused when it comes to conversions of units. Please bear with me this time.

What I know is that 1 BTU = 1056 Joules and that Kelvin to Rankine requires you to first convert it to Celsius then Fahrenheit then finally to Rankine.

Example: 8.314$\frac{J}{mol-K}$ to $\frac{BTU}{mol-R}$. What I've tried:

$(8.314\frac{J}{mol-K})*(\frac{1 BTU}{1056 J})*(\frac{1K}{-272.15°C})*(\frac{1°C}{33.8°F})*(\frac{1°F}{460})$ = -1.86 x 10$^{-9}$ $\frac{BTU}{mol-R}$

It is supposed to be 1.986 $\frac{BTU}{mol-R}$ but I couldn't get it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you~

Comment: 1 kelvin = 1.8 rankine; no need for Fahrenheit. And I often use google for this: https://www.google.com/search?q=5+btu+in+joules

Comment: @Pieter I'd like to learn it manually as in the classroom, you can't search on google while taking an exam. Thank you for the response, I appreciate it~ Also I can't seem to find a site where there they teach how to convert J/mol-K to BTU/mol-R. It's just showing online calculators and no solution on how to get it.

Comment: There is no other difficulty than knowing that there is a 9:5 ratio between the Rankine and the Kelvin scale. They both start at absolute zero.

Comment: @Pieter I have tried using 1K = 1.8 R and still didn't get the answer. (8.314)(1/1055)(1/1.8) = 4.37 x 10^-3. Any idea why I can't still get the correct answer?

Comment: That is correct according to this link: http://www.ipt.ntnu.no/~curtis/courses/PhD-PVT/PVT-HOT-Vienna-May-2016x/e-notes/MISC/Gas-Constant.pdf But then there may be imperial units for mole also??

Comment: I think the conversion is to btu/ lbmol. R
So, u need convert the grmol to lbmol